# SQL Query to find the houses where EVERYONE who lives there has watched a film longer than 100 minutes

Tags: sql, database

In my DB we have tables for people, the houses where they live, the existing TV programs and finally a table "watch" to keep track of who watches what and for how long. As from the title, I need to find the houses where EVERYONE who lives there has watched a film longer than 100 minutes. Now, I know how to get the houses where someone has watched a program for longer than 100 minutes, but I don't know how to check if everyone else in the house has also watched a film longer than 100 minutes. I did some research and found that with a self-join I could access data from the same table but even in this case I would only be able to check if only another person meets my criteria(or at least that's what I understood). Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
     DISTINCT H.id
FROM 
     house H, person P, watch W, program PR
WHERE 
    (H.id = P.house)
AND 
    (P.id = W.person)
AND 
    (W.program = PR.id)
AND 
    (PR.type = 'Film')
AND 
    (PR.minutes > 100)
AND 
    (W.seconds*60 = PR.length)
```

Can anyone tell me a way to do this?

Thank you very much,
Lorenzo

Comment: Can you provide your table structure....

Comment: Where does "V.seconds" come from?

Comment: Provide an example of how you want the result data to look, please.

Comment: Bad habits to kick (sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/…): using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 20 years ago) and its use is discouraged as @marc_s once responded to one of my answers

Comment: Sorry, that V was actually a W.

I want my result data to only include the id of every house that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Everybody longer than 100 minutes" means nobody's maximum is less than 100.

First find the maximum minutes for each person within a house and then check if the minimum of all person's maxes is greater than 100 minutes:

```
SELECT Hid
FROM
 (
    SELECT H.id AS Hid, PR.id AS PRid,
       -- maximum minutes per house/person
       MAX(PR.minutes) AS MaxMinutes
     FROM house H, person P, watch W, program PR
     WHERE (H.id = P.house)
       AND (P.id = W.person)
       AND (W.program = PR.id)
       AND (PR.type = 'Film')
       AND (V.seconds*60 = PR.length)
    GROUP BY H.id, PR.id
 ) dt
GROUP BY Hid
HAVING MIN(MaxMinutes) > 100 -- no person has a maximum less than 100 minutes
```

Edit:

Previous query returns households where everybody who watched a film did that for more than 100 minutes, people who never watched a film are not considered. In this case one might move the `(PR.type = 'Film')` condition from `WHERE` to `MAX`:

```
SELECT Hid
FROM
 (
    SELECT H.id AS Hid, PR.id AS PRid, 
       -- maximum minutes watching films per house/person
       MAX(CASE WHEN (PR.type = 'Film') THEN PR.minutes ELSE 0 END) AS MaxMinutes
     FROM house H, person P, watch W, program PR
     WHERE (H.id = P.house)
       AND (P.id = W.person)
       AND (W.program = PR.id)
       AND (V.seconds*60 = PR.length)
    GROUP BY H.id, PR.id
 ) dt
GROUP BY Hid
HAVING MIN(MaxMinutes) > 100 -- no person has a maximum less than 100 minutes
```

This still doesn't consider people who never watched anything, if you need it, go for @shawnt00's solution :)

Comment: Fix ambiguity in your query please. To which `id` does the outer select statement point? ;)

Comment: Your query actually says "Find household where everybody *who watched an entire film* watched one longer than 100 minutes." But it doesn't require that everybody in the household did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select h.id
from
    /* all people per household */
    house h inner join person p on p.house = h.id
    left outer join
    (
        /* find people who watched entire films of appropriate length */
        select distinct w.person
        from
            watch w inner join program pr
                on pr.id = w.program
        where
                pr.type = 'Film' and pr.minutes > 100
            and w.seconds * 60 = pr.length /* these really match to the second? */
    ) watchers
        on watchers.person = p.id
group by h.id
having count(*) = count(watchers.person) /* none are null meaning everybody watched a film */
```

You need to use an outer join since there could be people who didn't watch anything matching your criteria. An inner joins eliminates those people too early and defeats your attempts to discover those households where not everybody was a watcher.

The `having` condition is where it all comes together. The left join will cause a null value for `watchers.person` if that person didn't meet your conditions. Since `count(watchers.person)` does not count null values it's essentially saying that none of `watchers.person` in that group is null.